# How do I reference a system assembly in VS Code with Paket?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, paket

how do I best reference a system assembly, that has no NuGet package, in VS Code with Paket in an F# project or script?

Example: `System.Data.Linq.dll`.

One way is to hard reference the file, e.g. like this:

```
#r @"C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/System.Data.Linq.dll"
```

But is there a better / portable solution? How does this work with Mono or .NET Core?

Comment: In full .NET and in Mono you can simply use `#r "System.Data.Linq"` and F# will find the correct assembly. I'm not sure about .NET Core though.

Comment: @Tarmil Thx, I didn't know that. This is so easy that I haven't considered it.

Answer (score 0):

for a F# project in VSCode I include the reference in the .fsproj file.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- Other includes and stuff -->
  <Reference Include="System.Data.Linq" />
  <!-- Other includes and stuff -->
</ItemGroup>
```

Not sure how it works on .NET Core and Mono